# Проблема с парсером. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

headers = {"accept": "*/*",
           "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36"}

base_url = "http://hh.kz/search/vacancy?area=160&st=searchVacancy&text=python&from=suggest_post"

def hh_parse(base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = BS(base_url, "html.parser")
        divs = soup.find("div", attrs = {"data-qa": "vacancy-serp__vacancy"})
        for div in divs:
            title = div.find("a", attrs = {"data-qa": "vacancy-serp__vacancy-title"}).text
            href = div.find("a", attrs = {"data-qa": "vacancy-serp__vacancy-title"})["href"]
            print(href)
            print(title)
    else:
        print("error")

hh_parse(base_url, headers)
```

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\bs4__init__.py:389:
>   UserWarning:
>   "http://hh.kz/search/vacancy?area=160&st=searchVacancy&text=python&from=suggest_post"
>   looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should
>   probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind
>   the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Ну и зачем вы в BS передаёте урл?

Comment: Какое слово непонятно в написанном тексте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Beautiful Soup нужно передавать не ссылку, а сам html (в текстом виде), это делается через request.text, [документация по bs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), т.е.

`soup = BS(base_url, "html.parser")`

меняете на:

`soup = BS(request.text, "html.parser")`

и лучше вместо *request* писать общепринятую *r*, ибо первый вариант очень близок по названию как самому модулю и легко запутаться.